# How can I ensure a process is always running under any interactive logons on a specific workstation?

Tags: windows, process

Spinning this question off of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627404/how-can-i-have-a-service-run-a-process-under-the-current-users-session/5627612#5627612...

I have a service, written in C#, that monitors a set of files. It uses [Growl](http://www.growlforwindows.com) to notify the end-user if the modified time of one of these files is over 4 hours old. I've seen situations where Growl.exe was not running under the current user's session, thus they did not receive updates. How can I ensure that Growl is always running under any interactively logged on users' sessions on the machines that this service runs on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked out this article?

[MSDN: Interactive Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)